# CSS file is not getting emitted in the dist folder

Tags: webpack

This is my webpack.config file.I am trying to inject the bundle.css as a separate file into html.js file and the index.html are getting emitted in the dist folder but no luck with the css file.

EDITED: 
I dont want my bundled js,css file to added in the html or require via js.I want it to be injected.Now script file is automatically injected to the html file and i want the same to be happen for css file.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Digital</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<base href="/digi">
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack config file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './app/boot.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname) + '/dist',   
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }, 
    devtool: 'source-map',                         
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname),
        port: 9097
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        { 
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?sourceMap')
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|ttf|woff)/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000"
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [ 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html',
            inject: true
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
    ],
    resolve: {
    modules: ['./app/appManager/','./node_modules'],
    alias: {
       index: path.resolve(__dirname) + '/app',    
       root: path.resolve(__dirname)
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Webpack ignoring my CSS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347983/why-is-webpack-ignoring-my-css-files)

Comment: @MichaelJungo: please see my edited comments

Comment: `html-webpack-plugin` will automatically include the CSS file in a `<link>` tag, when it's extracted by `extract-text-webpack-plugin`. That doesn't change the fact that you need to import the CSS somewhere for webpack to process it. The CSS won't be in any JS, because it is fully extracted.